# Chrome Extension Holding onto Ghost Option in Storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have written a chrome extension in Manifest V3. I had an option, lets call it `ghostOption`, that I have removed from my code, but the option is still persisting in the list of options when I iterate through the list of options like so...

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(function(options) {
  Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
   console.log(key, "do stuff")
  })    
})
```

Tried reloading the extension, saving the options page, rebooting computer.

The solution I have found is to completely uninstall, and reinstall the extension. That's fine locally, but I am worried this might be a problem when I publish a new version to the web store. Does anyone know of a better way to deal with this problem?

Comment: You need to remove it from storage as well, not just from code. Use chrome.storage.sync.remove or chrome.storage.sync.clear.